# Possible character encoding issues?

Tags: php, android, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I am making a simple blog android app where users will be able to add/view blogs.Now for blog addition,there is a simple text-view where the users can add the blog content(blog text). That blog content is then transmitted to a php script via HttpPost, which then stores it in a MySQL database.

Now my problem is that users can copy-paste text for the blog content into the text-view.The source for this copy-paste could be anywhere ranging from internet pages to textbooks. Also the text could be of any font,color etc.This is possibly leading to character encoding issues,cos whenever i try to copy-paste text into blog body, the blog submission fails...otherwise it works fine.My MySQL database collation is UTF-8.

My question is :How to convert text from any possible source with any encoding to utf-8?

Comment: there's no reliable 100% foolproof way of figuring out what encoding a piece of text has. e.g. `cat` could be iso8859, or utf8 - there's absolutely no way to know, because for basic 'ascii' text, it's identical in ascii-type charsets and utf.

Comment: Do you have a `<meta ... charaset=utf-8>` on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

From their docs:

> You don't need to know what the encoding of your strings is. It can be Latin1 (iso 8859-1), Windows-1252 or UTF8, or the string can have a mix of them. \ForceUTF8\Encoding::toUTF8() will convert everything to UTF8.
>
> Sometimes you have to deal with services that are unreliable in terms of encoding, possibly mixing UTF8 and Latin1 in the same string